# Skip some row in jsf dataTable

Tags: jsf, components, seam

How to skip some rows to be displayed using dataTable:

`<h:dataTable cellspacing="0" id="dogs" value="#{dogBean.dogs}"  var="dog" rendered="#{dogBeans.dogs != null}">`

```
<h:column id="nameColumn">

    <h:outputText value="#{dog.name}"/>
</h:column>

<h:column id="breedColumn">

    <h:outputText value="#{dog.breed}"/>
</h:column>
```

`</h:dataTable>`

I want to display all dogs, but those how have an age greater than 10.
dog.age > 10.

I'm using Seam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this nicely in the view side. You can at most set the `rendered` attribute of every cell contents to `false`, but this doesn't avoid the `<tr>` element being rendered. You would see a blank row and its appearance may not be consistent among browsers.

Best is to filter the rows beforehand in the (post)construct, action(listener) or maybe lazily in the getter.

```
List<Dog> dogsOlderThan10 = new ArrayList<Dog>();
for (Dog dog : dogs) {
    if (dog.getAge() > 10) dogsOlderThan10.add(dog);
}
```

Or, just send a new SQL query returning exactly the data you need.

Comment: Nice piece of code. And it answers my initial question. jsf dataTable do not allow any sort of filtering on each element.

Comment: An issue with that though. my collection is actually a List, and this filter method returns a Collection (filtered collection implementation), now casting it to a list obviously fails.

Comment: Ah geez, fixed. I however wondered where's the `Lists#filter()` in Google Collections?

Comment: As transform() is in the Lists package, I would guess Lists filter has not been implemented.
Your new code is correct, but new allocation now :S

Comment: Yes indeed, forget it. Just loop over it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own renderer for datatable. For example, I use richfaces and I have the folowing renderer:

```
public class DetailDataTableRenderer extends DataTableRenderer {

    @Override
    public void encodeOneRow(FacesContext context, TableHolder tableHolder) throws IOException {
        Object obj = tableHolder.getTable().getRowData();
        if (obj instanceof BasicDTO) {
            BasicDTO dto = (BasicDTO)obj;
            if (dto.isSkipRow()) {
                return;
            }
        }
        super.encodeOneRow(context, tableHolder);
    }
}
```

and I registered my renderer as

```
<renderer>
    <component-family>org.richfaces.DataTable</component-family>
    <renderer-type>org.richfaces.DataTableRenderer</renderer-type>
    <renderer-class>myframework.view.component.DetailDataTableRenderer</renderer-class>     
</renderer>
```

I hope it helped.

Cesar.

Comment: Nice, I never thought of extending the existing renderer. It's an old question, the project is now completed so found the work around given by BalusC. Thanks for this solution though. I will def try it next time I'm on a Seam dev task at work.